# How to define uri adress for GET method in REST

Tags: c#, rest, messagecontract, uritemplate

I had this code, and everything worked well

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
         ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
         UriTemplate = "Product/{id}?fields={fieldsParam}")]
    ResponseData JSONData(string id, string fieldsParam);
```

I changed my code into format:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
         UriTemplate = "Product/{id}?fields={fieldsParam}")]
    Message JSONData(RetrievePublishedDataInput input);
```

Where

```
 [MessageContract]
    public class RetrievePublishedDataInput
    {
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public string fieldsParam { get; set; }
    }
```

But there is an error. There is no way to use `MessageContract` with `UriTemplate`, but how I can specify a service address with request arguments?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Cannot run the service. Operation in contract uses parameters of UriTemplate, but also uses parameter MessageContract. Parameters MessageContract and UriTemplates are not compatible